# Are UI events queued and processed in the same order they were triggered

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

In a WP7 app (or Silverlight), are events triggered from the UI queued and processed in the same order they were triggered? For instance, if I am very quickly clicking button1, button2 and button3, are the three click events will run in the same sequence and sequentially (on the UI thread).

I am trying to get a confirmation on that. I can't seem to find any documentation to back this up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because the UI events are all handled on the same UI thread. When you're talking about a single thread, there is no "concurrency". Because of this, other UI events can't be triggered while another one is being handled -- they are *not* queued and handled in an order like you're suspecting. If fact, you can put a `Thread.Sleep` in a button click handler and freeze up the UI (you can't click the other buttons). After the Sleep statement times out and the handler exists, *then* the UI would become responsive again and you'd be able to click the next button.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are correct. When I use the Click event a of button I see the events being executed sequentially. However, if I use the Tap event, some of the event seem to be skipped...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, that will run like a concurrent task/activity in UI thread.